# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake.all'

Tags: python, drake

Installed the Stable version of Drake using instructions provided at: https://drake.mit.edu/pip.html#stable-releases.
Getting a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrake.all'
```

when using

```
python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'
```

Installing with Python 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.6.
a
I had installed the previous stable versions and had not gotten any errors.

Kindly help.

Comment: How did you install it ? python3 may not use the same python intrepreter as your installer's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me.  Here's exactly what I did:

```
jwnimmer@cons:~/tmp$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
jwnimmer@cons:~/tmp$ python3 -m venv env
jwnimmer@cons:~/tmp$ env/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
...
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2
jwnimmer@cons:~/tmp$ env/bin/pip install drake
...
Successfully installed PyYAML-6.0 contourpy-1.0.7 cycler-0.11.0 drake-1.15.0 fonttools-4.39.3 importlib-resources-5.12.0 kiwisolver-1.4.4 matplotlib-3.7.1 numpy-1.24.3 packaging-23.1 pillow-9.5.0 pydot-1.4.2 pyparsing-3.0.9 python-dateutil-2.8.2 six-1.16.0 zipp-3.15.0
jwnimmer@cons:~/tmp$ source env/bin/activate
(env) jwnimmer@cons:~/tmp$ python3 -c 'import pydrake.all; print(pydrake.__file__)'
/home/jwnimmer/tmp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrake/__init__.py
```

Can you please share in more detail exactly what you did, e.g., copy-paste of the terminal buffer of the commands you ran and its output?

Comment: It seems to be working fine now. I have no idea what changed. I deleted the previous environment and completed all the installation steps and it works fine. Thanks for your help.